# jquery change attr href with value from select

Tags: jquery, select, attr

I have this form :

```
<div id="select_1">
<select class="select-class">
    <option value="value_1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="value_2">2</option>
    <option value="value_3">3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="a-class">Link</a> 
</div> 

<div id="select_2">
<select class="select-class">
    <option value="value_1">1</option>
    <option value="value_2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="value_3">3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="a-class">Link</a> 
</div>

<div id="select_3">
<select class="select-class">
    <option value="value_1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="value_2">2</option>
    <option value="value_3">3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="a-class">Link</a> 
</div>
```

For each line of select item, I want to change attr href with this value :
href="url.com?"+ value of option selected from select

How can i do this with jquery ?

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am I understanding you correctly if I assume that, when the user selects an option from one of the **select** elements, the adjacent **a** element should be updated? In that case:

```
// jquery 1.7
$(function() {
    $("select.select-class").on("change", function() {
        var link = $(this).parent().find("a.a-class");
        link.attr("href", "url.com?" + $(this).val());
    });
}
```

It could also be that you want to update all **a** elements when the document is loaded in the browser. In that case:

```
$(function() {
    $("select.select-class").each(function() {
        var link = $(this).parent().find("a.a-class");
        link.attr("href", "url.com?" + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn t work...
I have to put your code in $(document).ready(function () ?

Comment: Yes, and you can use the shortcut `$(function() {...`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have an another question (maybe i have to post a new question, let me know...).
How can i do if i have 2 select like this :

`<div id="select_1">
<select class="select-class-1">

    <option value="value_1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="value_2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="select-class-2">
    <option value="value_1">1</option>
    <option value="value_2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="a-class">Link</a> 
</div>
...
`

my attr will be : url.com?x=value select1&y=value select2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5709/discussion-between-atornblad-and-adokara)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the `href attr` of the a tag after the value of the select is changed. You can try the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/ZyJfG/1/), it sets the `href` attribute of the link every time the value of the select box is changed.

```
$('select.select-class').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    var url = "url.com?";
    url += $(this).val();
    $(this).next().attr('href', url);
});
```